# OpenCart: стандартное значение опции (Вычитать со склада - нет)

Tags: opencart

Как сделать, чтобы в OpenCart: 2.1.0.1 по стандарту было значение опции Вычитать со склада - нет?

Пробовал это:

> в файле \admin\controller\catalog\product.php примерно строка 869
>   $this->data['subtract'] = 1; меняем на $this->data['subtract'] = 0;

Пробовал и это:

```html
html += '    <td class="left"><select name="product_option[' + option_row + '][product_option_value][' + option_value_row + '][subtract]">';
    html += '      <option value="1"><?php echo $text_yes; ?></option>';
    html += '      <option value="0"><?php echo $text_no; ?></option>';
    html += '    </select></td>';
```

Не помогает, почему-то значение всегда стоит на "Да".

Comment: может на базе значения по умолчанию поменять?

Answer (score 2):

В файле

```
/admin/controller/catalog/product.php
```

Найти

```
$data['subtract'] = 1;
```

Заменить на

```
$data['subtract'] = 0;
```

Учтите, что это именно по умолчанию, у уже сохранненых товаров этот параметр нужно задавать - в ручную, или через БД, или через импорт - в общем, как получится.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/admin/controller/catalog/product.php#L891

По умолчанию стоит `1` - истина.

Comment: пробовал, не работает)

Comment: поищи где js вешает на select дефолтное значение

Comment: через chrome (F12) правой кнопкой на select -> Break on.. -> Attributes Modifications.

Comment: <select name="product_option[0][product_option_value][0][subtract]" class="form-control">    <option value="1">Да</option>    <option value="0">Нет</option>  </select>

Comment: поставь selected на "Да" по дефолту )

Comment: как? я уже сменил все с "0" на "1" везде, где только можно))

Comment: с таким подходом вообще запутаетесь)